# Checking clustered EJBs in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing

I am testing a J2EE application in a clustered Weblogic 10.3.5 environment.
As described in http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/cluster/failover.html#wp1044561, I have configured the following in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml:

```
<stateless-clustering>
<home-is-clusterable>true</home-is-clusterable>
<stateless-bean-is-clusterable>true</stateless-bean-is-clusterable>
</stateless-clustering>
```

for each EJB (they are all stateless session beans).

How can I test that the EJBs are actually clustered ? That is, what changes should I look for with respect to not specifying the  block ?

Answer (score 0):

The clustered object keeps track of replicas incase the primary server is unavailable. You could fire up your application, perform the business logic required for the application to cache the EJB home and then bring down the primary server it is using. You can track this either through the debug or access logs.

Once the primary server is unavailable, try performing another business action that will use the bean and see if it recognizes that the cached home interface is unavailable and proceeds to use a replica.

If you not implement the `<home-is-clusterable>` option, the application should error out after the primary node is made unavailable. Hope that helps.